# SignalR change port - SelfHost

Tags: c#, client-server, signalr, port, self-hosting

I am trying to change the port of my server using a remote request.
When I do that it seems that everything is ok but when I try to connect I get an exception.

If I close(terminate process) and then open(start process) the server with the new port everything works fine(the clients manages to connect).

**Server:**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static IDisposable _webApp = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = Start(8089);
        Stop();
        var uri = Start(8089);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string Start(int port)
    {
        var options = new StartOptions();
        var uri = string.Format("http://*:{0}/", port);
        options.Urls.Add(uri);
        options.Settings.Add(typeof(ITraceOutputFactory).FullName, typeof(NullTraceOutputFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);// disable built-in owin tracing by using a null traceoutput
        var startup = new Startup
            {
                Restart = Restart
            };
        _webApp = WebApp.Start(options, startup.Configuration);
        Trace.Listeners.Remove("HostingTraceListener"); // remove the built-in owin listener
        Console.WriteLine("Server running at " + uri);
        return uri;
    }

    private static void Stop()
    {
        _webApp.Dispose();
    }

    private static string Restart(int port)
    {
        Stop();
        var uri = Start(port);
        return uri;
    }

    internal class NullTraceOutputFactory : ITraceOutputFactory
    {
        public TextWriter Create(string outputFile)
        {
            return StreamWriter.Null;
        }
    }
}

[HubName("Configuration")]
public class ConfigurationHub : Hub
{
    private Func<int, string> _restart;

    public ConfigurationHub(Func<int, string> restart)
    {
        _restart = restart;
    }

    public void ChangePort(int port)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Port: " + port);
        _restart(port);
    }
}

internal class Startup
{
    public Func<int, string> Restart;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(ConfigurationHub),
                () => new ConfigurationHub(Restart));
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        //app.UseWelcomePage();
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true,
#if DEBUG
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
#endif
        };

        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IHubProxy _configurationProxy = null;
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private const string CATEGORY = "ABCD";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateProxy(8089);
        _hubConnection.Start().Wait();
    }

    private void btnChangePort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newPort = Int32.Parse(btnChangePort.Tag as string);
        _configurationProxy.Invoke("ChangePort", newPort);
        _hubConnection.Stop();
        _hubConnection.Dispose();
        _hubConnection = null;
        CreateProxy(newPort);
        _hubConnection.Start().Wait(); // <= Exception when clicking the button
    }

    private void CreateProxy(int newPort)
    {
        //var address = "127.0.0.1";
        var address = "192.168.0.100";
        var port = newPort;
        var config =
            new
                {
                    Name = "Configuration",
                    Pattern = "http://{0}:{1}",
                    Address = address,
                    Port = newPort,
                    QueryString = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "version", "1.0" } },
                    Methods = new[]
                        {
                            "notifyWrongVersion",
#if ERROR
                                "notifyConnected",
#endif
                            //"status",
                            "notifyByeBye"
                        },
                    MethodsCallbacks = new Action[]
                        {
                            () => Console.WriteLine("{0}: You are using the wrong version!", CATEGORY),
#if ERROR
                                    () => Trace.WriteLine("Connected to server! HOORAY!", Categories.CATEGORY_THIS),
#endif
                            () =>
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}: Bye bye from the server. Thank you for discnnecting.", CATEGORY)
                        },
                };

        var url = String.Format(config.Pattern, config.Address, config.Port);

        _hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);
        _hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
        _hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;
        _configurationProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy(config.Name);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**
[image: Exception]

**Scenario:**
Started with port 8089 on client and server
Pressed the button on client and server changed to 8088
Closed the client
Opened the client with port 8088.

**Client Logging:**

> 14:04:18.2450308 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
>   14:04:18.7762877 - 708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - WS
>   Connecting to:
>   ws://192.168.250.9:8088/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=webSockets&connectionData=[{"Name":"Configuration"}]&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAVaJK6bsSpkyFVlk1Ej463gAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAAcSxXM3loQOfD31c8mYLdqAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAISDmfaiIg%2By%2FVt3bBI%2BZkAoAAAAd%2FngqVkiFGH55BN9NOW4nljYZzHBBwoTLxNwrj%2B31AiShmmgS6euMBQAAADjFYeiwsjjJ%2BRVX92GYdozAkKthw%3D%3D
>   14:04:23.8220044 - 708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - Auto: Failed
>   to connect to using transport webSockets. System.TimeoutException:
>   Transport timed out trying to connect 14:04:23.8220044 -
>   708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - SSE: GET
>   http://192.168.250.9:8088/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=serverSentEvents&connectionData=[{"Name":"Configuration"}]&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAVaJK6bsSpkyFVlk1Ej463gAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAAcSxXM3loQOfD31c8mYLdqAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAISDmfaiIg%2By%2FVt3bBI%2BZkAoAAAAd%2FngqVkiFGH55BN9NOW4nljYZzHBBwoTLxNwrj%2B31AiShmmgS6euMBQAAADjFYeiwsjjJ%2BRVX92GYdozAkKthw%3D%3D
>   14:04:23.9157549 - 708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - WS:
>   OnClose() 14:04:23.9157549 - 708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c -
>   SSE: OnMessage(Data: initialized) 14:04:28.8486354 -
>   708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - Auto: Failed to connect to
>   using transport serverSentEvents. System.TimeoutException: Transport
>   timed out trying to connect 14:04:28.8642594 -
>   708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - LP Connect:
>   http://192.168.250.9:8088/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=longPolling&connectionData=[{"Name":"Configuration"}]&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAVaJK6bsSpkyFVlk1Ej463gAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAAAcSxXM3loQOfD31c8mYLdqAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAISDmfaiIg%2By%2FVt3bBI%2BZkAoAAAAd%2FngqVkiFGH55BN9NOW4nljYZzHBBwoTLxNwrj%2B31AiShmmgS6euMBQAAADjFYeiwsjjJ%2BRVX92GYdozAkKthw%3D%3D
>   14:04:33.8799023 - 708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - Auto: Failed
>   to connect to using transport longPolling. System.TimeoutException:
>   Transport timed out trying to connect 14:04:33.8799023 -
>   708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - Disconnected 14:04:33.8799023 -
>   708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c -
>   Transport.Dispose(708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c)
>   14:04:33.8799023 - 708038b9-66b0-4cc2-95ac-de45411e453c - Closed

after 3 times getting this error I get also this:

> 14:14:24.0350106 - null - OnError(System.TimeoutException: The client
>   has been inactive since 31/05/2015 14:13:27 and it has exceeded the
>   inactivity timeout of 00:00:50. Stopping the connection.)

Comment: Pls add exception + stack trace into your question..

Comment: OK. Are you sure the server is running after the restart? If you try open `Http://<new server IP and port>/signalr/hubs` in browser, does it work ?

Comment: Yes. It works before and after the change.

Comment: If server runs and client is unable to connect (timeout), problem has to be in client right ? Did you try to activate [SignalR tracing](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#net_client) in client ?

Comment: Updated the question with the trace from the client. I think the problem is in the server side(look at the beginning of the question with the open and close of the process).

Comment: Ok, that trace is not very useful indeed. By beginning of the post you mean _If I close(terminate process) and then open(start process) the server with the new port everything works fine(the clients manages to connect)._ ? Im not sure i understand this sentence. For example - how can you open server with new port when you have port number (old one) specified directly in server code. Can you pls clarify the exact order of steps ?

Comment: STEPS: I start the server with port 2000. Now I give an order to change the port. The server restarts. All this is shown in the code. Now I stop the server. Change the port manually to 3000 (In the real code I have a configuration being updated so no need to change manually). Start the server.

Comment: But this sounds like server is not restarted properly (it is not listening on the new port). I was asking exactly that few comments ago and you said that server is running and accessible. I'm perplexed ;) Does it mean that after restart (from code), the server is accessible from browser but SignalR client is not able to connect ?

Comment: Exactly. If you want you can try to run the code and see it happens to you also. I added a stop and then start on the server and now it seems I can change ports but not use the new connection. I get the following exception: "Data cannot be sent because the connection is in the disconnected state. Call start before sending any data". Please take a look at the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work doing following changes:

1) Let client and server have time to finish before disconnecting (client) or disposing (server)

Server:

```
public void ChangePort(int port)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received ChangePort request: " + port);
    Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ => _restart(port));
}
```

Client:

```
_configurationProxy.Invoke("ChangePort", port)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ChangePort faulted: {0}", task.Exception.Flatten()); 
        }

        _hubConnection.Stop();
        _hubConnection.Dispose();
        _hubConnection = null;
    }).Wait();
```

2) It seems there is an issue with `DependencyResolver` being disposed during server dispose and never coming back (see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3051)). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759813/signalr-client-is-reconnected-after-owin-restart-but-message-is-not-published) describes very similar issue you are having. This is solution:

```
internal class Startup
    {
        public Func<int, string> Restart;

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
            resolver.Register(typeof(ConfigurationHub), () => new ConfigurationHub(Restart));

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                Resolver = resolver
            };

            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your code but after changing the port and trying to invoke another method from the hub I got the following exception on the client: Data cannot be sent because the connection is in the disconnected state. Call start before sending any data. Please see the full project at the following link: http://bit.do/SignalR

Comment: Code from your link is different from code in question and frankly it's a mess.
I'v modified my solution so that after client connects back to server running on a new port (after restart), it immediately calls different method on server (not restart one) and server call back client. It works. 
You can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nerka03wx95m8l/SignalR.ServerRestart.zip?dl=0).

I'v provided solution to your question which you are not able to replicate or accept and i'm not willing to waste more time with you...

Answer (score 0):

we have similar case!  instead of change port, i need to restart client side or Server side.

I use a timer and a global flag 'is connected' to acheive the purpose.  e.g. if not connected then try catch the connect function in client every 5 seconds, it is usually OK at the second try unless there is no connection, it usually failed at the first try since the restart of Server is not fast enough!

Comment: Even if I delay the reconnect after the port change I get the same exception

Comment: can you try taking away the createproxy and start connection in the btnchange and put them inside Another button?

Comment: I can see the differences, in Server side you dispose  webapp and restart!

Comment: Why is it a problem to dispose the webapp?

Comment: try to 'try catch' all codes inside the createproxy to see if there is any error message

Comment: will there be any problem after you dispose _wepapp and use _webapp = webapp.start again?

Comment: I added a stop and then start on the server and now it seems I can change ports but not use the new connection. I get the following exception: "Data cannot be sent because the connection is in the disconnected state. Call start before sending any data". Please take a look at the updated code.

Comment: since I'm using signalr client as a native app. in Android or iPhone, I assume that anything will happen with the connection, e.g. Server stopped, slow connection, reconnecting, whatever.  So I have a heartbeat function in the client, such that anything unexpected happens, I restart the client connection as if it is the first time load of the Client.  In your codes, I cannot see this kind of design, may be you don't need to use slow connection in client.