# SignalR client does not receive messages after a reconnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using signalR with a javascript client to provide a progress bar for a long running powershell task in the backend of a web application. Sortly after the the task is started, it causes the app pool to recycle (this happens when the powershell is invoked and I can't seem to get round this), signalR performs a reconnection and this looks successful, but the progress messages stop coming through. If i debug the path, stepping through the code, the messages are still coming up from the powershell, and the broadcast is called, but the client does not receive anything.

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Hub:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public void SendProgress(string progressMessage, int progressCount)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();

        hubContext.Clients.All.AddProgress(progressMessage, progressCount);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
var progress = $.connection.progressHub;
console.log(progress);

progress.client.addProgress = function (message, percentage) {

    $('#actionDetail').html(message);

    $("#progressBar").progressbar({
        value: percentage
    });             
};

$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    var connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
    console.log(connectionId);
});
```

Client Logs:

```
[10:07:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://2012r2-en-09:7750/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientP…BoA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=10'.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:40 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
VM145:1 718e2f95-4950-4350-8dff-4b7cb9f1158a
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:46 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:46 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting due to the server connection ending.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:48 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:48 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:48 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://2012r2-en-09:7750/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&messa…SBoA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=7'.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
VM145:1 718e2f95-4950-4350-8dff-4b7cb9f1158a
5jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:07:59 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'AddProgress' on hub 'ProgressHub'.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:08:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:08:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting due to the server connection ending.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:08:08 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:08:08 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:08:08 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://2012r2-en-09:7750/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&messa…SBoA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=9'.
jquery?v=WM6erXjzG36po83czfGO2Wf5wbUN0yj0TfE47rwndb41:1 
[10:08:10 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
VM145:1 718e2f95-4950-4350-8dff-4b7cb9f1158a
```

From the logs, you can see after the initial connection, a reconnection is performed, after this one the messages still continue to come through. It is after the second one where the app pool is recycled they stop.

There are similar questions out there, such as this one: [SignalR client is reconnected after Owin restart, but message is not published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759813/signalr-client-is-reconnected-after-owin-restart-but-message-is-not-published[1]) However, trying the solution mentioned he stops all messages coming through even prior to the reconnection.

Comment: From your code i cant see where you call `SendProgress`

Comment: SendProgress is called from the controller class, a delegate callback is passed into the backend methods, which calls back to the controller, which in turn calls SendProgress. If I step through the code this works as expected, after the app pool recycles we still call into SendProgress, but the client does not receive the messages.

Comment: Did you debug to ser where it stop or what that that dont get called?

Comment: The code in your hub method `SendProgress` doesn't need to call `GetHubContext`.  Just replace with: `Clients.All.AddProgress(progressMessage, progressCount);`

Comment: If i do that I get the error message "Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported."

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue when SignalR disconnected and fixed the problem on the client's side by completely recreating the signalR hub object:

```
// SignalR disconnected callback:
$.connection.hub.disconnected(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Reset the SignalR hub and recreate the hub proxies:
        $.signalR.hub = null;
        $.signalR.hub = $.hubConnection('/signalr', { useDefaultPath: false });
        $.extend($.signalR, $.signalR.hub.createHubProxies());

        // Re-subscribe to your events:
        $.connection.myHub.client.onMessage = message => {
            console.log(`onMessage[MyHub]: ${message}`);
        };
        
        // SignalR restart:
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000);
});
```

We saw in the logs that our `onMessage` function wasn't getting triggered after it disconnected (and supposedly reconnected), so recreating the hub connection and calling the `createHubProxies()` before connecting again worked. We tested this locally by timing out the connection (adding a breakpoint somewhere in the server code) which triggered the `disconnected()` function.

Answer (score 0):

1. once you request the task, you should return task-id to client.
2. store the task-id somewhere in client side (localstorage or cookie) and on reconnecting you have to subscribe for the progress of that task-id.

ps: You will need this function even user reload the page accidentally.